# Why aren't I able to perform simple arithmetic operations in python using Vscode but I can elsewhere

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, math

essentially when I run something as simple as '3 * 3' in any other IDE I have no issues, however, all arithmetic operations in my Vscode seem to return nothing, the terminal just repeats my PWD essentially.

Note that I am new and learning python but everything else thus far has worked fine, print statements print to the terminal etc but maths docent seem to work.

```
enter code here: def example(val1, val2):
                     return val1 * val2
                 example(2, 6)
```

Edit: by terminal I mean I am writing the script and clicking the run button in vscode which outputs to said terminal, I have uploaded a SC of what I mean :[screenshot of the IDE and terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb6gv.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need more information to help you. When you say "all arithmetic operations in my VS Code seem to return nothing", what do you mean exactly? What exact steps do you perform that "return nothing"? Is your python code in a file? If so, how do you run that file? Are you typing directly in the terminal in VS Code? Are you doing something else? Please give a step-by-step description of what you are doing.

Comment: You need to `print()` or something along those lines in order to get output.

Comment: Are you sure that in VSCode you are in a Python shell and not in a Bash shell?

Comment: Provide your screenshots so that we have clear idea of the problem

Comment: Just to clarify, you're typing expressions into some terminal in vscode, not writing and then running a Python .py file? Does this terminal display a prompt? Does it look like a Python interactive prompt (usually `>>>`) ?

Comment: Hi thank you all for the fast responses, I have edited my post, maybe this will add some clarity to my matter.

Comment: What @Axe319 said: there's no output because there's nothing in your script that asks Python to produce any output. Try `print(example(2, 6))` instead of `example(2, 6)`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson you and Axe319 were completely right, I am sorry this is such a trivial question, it seems the guide I was watching was running it in jypter notebooks and did require such a print function. 

Thank you everyone once more for the quick and helpful replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some environments, such as the Python REPL (the P stands for "print") and Jupyter Notebook), results are printed out automatically. However, when you run a script from the command line or VS Code, printing isn't automatic. To output something in this case, you need to add a `print()` command:

```
def example(val1, val2):
  return val1 * val2
result = example(2, 6)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal is running a shell, probably `bash` not python.

Then, if you want to evaluate that in `bash` do

```
$(( 3 * 3 ))
```

Comment: I have edited my original post maybe this will add some clarity to what I mean